# Mongo TTL cleanup is not working

Tags: python, mongodb, ttl

I'm trying to get Mongo to remove documents with the TTL feature however without success. Have tried many things but mongo doesn't seem to clean up.

My index:

```
    {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "date" : 1
    },
    "name" : "date_1",
    "ns" : "history.history",
    "expireAfterSeconds" : 60
}
```

The date value from document:

```
       "date" : "2016-09-29 11:08:46.461207",
```

Output from db.serverStatus().metrics.ttl:

```
{ "deletedDocuments" : NumberLong(0), "passes" : NumberLong(29) }
```

Time output from db.serverStatus():

```
"localTime" : ISODate("2016-09-29T11:19:45.345Z")
```

Only thing I suspect is the way I insert the value from Python. Could be that it's in some way wrong. I have a JSON document which contains the following element:

```
"date": str(datetime.utcnow()),
```

Any clues where the problem might lay?

Thanks,
Janis

Answer (score 3):

As you have guessed, the problem is in how you insert the date value. I'll quote the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/):

> If the indexed field in a document is not a date or an array that
>   holds a date value(s), the document will not expire.

You are casting the date to a string. If you are using the pymongo driver, he will handle datetimes nicely and convert it to MongoDB native [Date type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date).

This way, the following should work:

```
"date": datetime.utcnow()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried that and get exception: datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 30, 6, 33, 2, 771754) is not JSON serializable. I guess due to the fact that I'm executing json.dumps() on the prepered JSON document.

Comment: @JanisJansons pymongo handles python dictionaries and lists and most types correctly, no need to use json.dumps().

Comment: thanks. How silly of me doing that ;) Removed the code and all is good now, can see the cleanup working as expected. Thanks all.